# Xcode c code build success but doesn't run

Tags: c, xcode, compilation

I am looking for help with something about Xcode. this code runs successful on the youtube video. on my MacBook it build successful but doesn't run, the windows on the right bottom side is always blank as shown in the picture.I am new to this application so I don't know where I did wrong. I followed every step with the video.Can someone help me solve this? thank you.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z06SQ.jpg)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Hi,thank you but it still blank there, doesn't work at all. The code in tutorial is same as mine but it works.

Comment: In your screenshot your Dock obscures drop down so not sure what is selected, but make sure that in debugger output area "All Output" or "Target Output" is selected

Comment: try `printf("...message...");fflush(stdout);`

Comment: @Mindaugas Both them are selected as what you comment, but it doesn't show things.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you again, but it still doesn't work. I am not sure it's the setting problem or the bug of Xcode.

Comment: Please insert your code into the question, instead of linking to a screenshot of it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved now, It's because of the bug in the vision 8.3.1 of xcode. 8.3.2 works now>